# Is Karma Tast Runner working on node js v0.12.0?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, gulp, karma-runner

I use node.js v0.12.0 and i have installed karma to my OS X Yosemite  but when i run my test task with gulp it waits like in the picture. It doesn't start PhantomJs. I tried the same code in node version of  v0.10.32 and it works but it doesn't work in nodejs v0.12.0. So How can i run karma to node.js v0.12.0?

[image: when karma run it waits]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no. Karma v0.12.31 is incompatible with the latest stable version of Nodejs (v0.12.0). On the Karma website, under [Installation > Installing Node.js](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/intro/installation.html) there is a disclaimer:

> **Note:** Karma works on the two latest stable versions. That is 0.8.x and 0.10.x at this point.

Even though the latest stable version of Nodejs is v0.12, the Karma team has not yet updated the project to support it. There is an open issue on Github for the project:

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1328

You can install an earlier 0.10.x release of Nodejs using [node version manager (nvm)](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to support the current release of Karma. With `nvm`, you can have multiple versions of `node` installed on your machine to mitigate this very issue.

```
// Install NVM
$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.24.0/install.sh | bash
...
// Quit and reopen the shell
$ nvm install 0.10
$ nvm use 0.10
// Assuming you're in the project directory
$ npm install
...
$ gulp test
```